# Entity Framework code first for Oracle

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, oracle11g

Is there any possibility of using EF Code First for Oracle DB.

Even though the DB generation is absent is there a way to the use the EF fluent API with Oracle DB.

Comment: Can I use EF Code First using ODP.NET ? ODAC 12c not supports EF Code First.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, actually we are using right now in a new project, but we had a lot of problems, some of them are not fixed yet.

Take a look at this:

[Oracle ODP.Net and EF CodeFirst - edm.decimal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094567/oracle-odp-net-and-ef-codefirst-edm-decimal-error)

and this:

[Oracle ODP.Net and EF CodeFirst - SaveChanges Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930487/oracle-odp-net-and-ef-codefirst-savechanges-error)

Comment: Can I use EF Code First using ODP.NET ? ODAC 12c not supports EF Code First.

Comment: Yes, you can. We actually used it successfully in a project right now in production.

Comment: Alex Keh from Oracle, says ODAC 12c NOT suuport EF CODE FIRST. Any full code source sample about it ?