# How to create an EF Code First implementation via Reverse Engineering of an existing DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been running a prototype Code First implementation of EF 5 for around a year now, but now management has said yes, and its time to apply the prototype to the entire database.

When I first coded the Code First items, I used the EF Powertools to Reverse Engineer the Code First items. That gave me a Context which I then updated, and a plethora of POCO classes for each table, and a Map class for each Entity.

Is this still the best way to create a Code First implementation?

I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116) that I could also generate a Code First Model via the `DbContext Generator`, however when I try this, it appears I have to create a new `*.edmx` file from the existing database, from which I can then use the DbContext Generator.

However, when I do the first step here, and create the `*.edmx` file, I can see the POCO classes and the context being generated. Do I need the `DbContext Generator` at all? I mean what does that bring to the table that I don't have already?

From what I can see, the Map files are not generated, but instead the data previously held in that file is now part of the `Entities.Designer.cs` file instead, but there is a lot more code now for handling object changes etc.

[EDIT] Can anyone give any example of how a Code First implementation should be built when reverse engineering an existing database?

*If it helps, I am using EF6 and connecting to an Oracle database using ODAC v11.2.*

Answer (score 1):

I create entities as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{get;set;}

    public string Name{get;set;}

    public string GroupName{get;set;}

    public CustomerGroup Group{get;set;}
}

public class CustomerGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{get;set;}

    public string Name{get;set;}

    public List<Customer> Groups{get;set;}
}
```

Then you need a context that inherits from DB context

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers{get;set;}
    public DbSet<CustomerGroup> Groups{get;set;}
}
```

if you have a connection string in the App.Config with the name of your context class you can instantiate the context and it should create a database with the given entities at the location given in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these links, they'll help you for sure:)

[Oracle odp and entity](http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/01/oracle-odp-and-entity-framework-code-first-4-2)

and some on this site as well.

[An answered error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094567/oracle-odp-net-and-ef-codefirst-edm-decimal-error)

and this

[SaveChanges error help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930487/oracle-odp-net-and-ef-codefirst-savechanges-error)

I've never worked with oracle but i can entity framework code first so yea take a look at them.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my github project. I have implemented code first, unit of work and repository pattern there. You can use this as start up project.

https://github.com/erandika1986/CodeFirst

Thanks,
Erandika